# Load objects which have been initialized before attaching

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to load objects through bytecode instrumentation , using `asm` framework.

Now , when I am using `premain` , all the objects I can track accurately. But, with `attach` , is there any way out to do so ?

Let's take an example :

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void insertValues(int limit){
        if(list!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now , if this list is not called again ( which I can track from `visitFieldInsn` : `GETFIELD` opcode ) , I can not load this object , right ?

Is there any workaround from this problem ?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated .

Comment: It’s not quite clear what you want to achieve, i.e. what you mean with “load this object”. If you want to get hands on all already existing live objects, that’s not possible with Instrumentation. You need JVM TI for that…

Comment: @Holger : By "load this object" , I just meant to track the object. Isn't there any other way in `instrumentation` API or using `bytecode modification`, which can achieve the same ?

Comment: Your question already contains the answer to that. It doesn’t matter how you transform the code *after* its execution. You can only change the behavior of subsequent executions. Getting hands on already existing objects is not foreseen by the Instrumentation API. You need JVM TI but the good news is that [there’s a Java API for it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/).

Comment: @Holger : Thanks for the `JDI` link , earlier I knew only about `JVMTI` and `instrumentation` approach. But due to complexity in `JVMTI` , I tend to avoid it. I would definitely deep dive into `JDI` and let you know :-) 

(and though off-topic , may I request something : if my question seems to show some research effort and useful , can you please upvote ?  )